# Cannot implicitly convert type 'long' to "int?"?

Tags: c#, types, long-integer, nullable

It a very simple question - convert a type long variable to a Nullable int type (int?). (see example below- not the actual code)

```
int? y = 100;

long x = long.MaxValue;

y = x;
```

I am getting compile time error.

"Cannot implicitly convert type 'long' to 'int?'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?).

I do have the fix ( see below the solution section), My curiosity in posting the question is of the 3 solutions which one is recommended?

Solution

```
  y = Convert.ToInt32(x);
  y = (int)x;
  y = unchecked((int) x);
```

Thanks in advance for your suggestions

Comment: Do you know why the compiler is complaining about this? It is trying to help you.

Comment: David - I am completely aware of loss of precision ( loosing the value), my question was of the 3 which is recommended( above is just an example)

Comment: Which one is recommended depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you require an *explicit* conversion is that not all values of `long` can be represented as an `int`.  The compiler is more or less saying 'you *can* do this, but you have to tell me you know what you're doing'.

Per [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4haekc4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), `Convert.ToInt32` will check for and throw an `OverflowException` if the `long` cannot be represented as an `int`.  You can see the implementation in the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,bdb2bfd045e3633e) - it's just this check and then a cast.

The second two options are (usually) the same and allow the cast despite an overflow as `unchecked` [is the compiler default](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a569z7k8.aspx).  If you change the compiler default to checked [using the /checked switch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h25wtyxf.aspx) then you'll get an `OverflowException` if not in an `unchecked` block.

As to which is 'best', it depends what your requirement is.

Comment: The second two options are not the same.  The first will throw an exception if compiled with overflow checking, and the second won't.

Comment: @phoog yes.  That was sort of implied by saying it was the default and linking to the docs, but I'll try and make clearer.

Answer (score 4):

`int` is 32-bit integral while `long` is 64-bit integral.

`long` can store/represent all `int` values but all `long` values cannot be represented by `int` so `long` is bigger type than `int` that's why `int` can be implicitly converted to `long` by compiler but not vice versa.

So that's the reason we need to explicitly cast/convert `long` to `int` which may result in information loss if that `long` is not representable as`int`