# Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'long' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

This is my C# code: how to i rectify this error.?

```
    private MyFinger.MyKAD MyKad = new MyFinger.MyKAD();
    void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       int MyKADSts = 0;

    MyKADSts = MyKad.Connect();
    //ShowMsg("MyKad.Connect_MyKad():" + MyKADSts);
    //Button3.Enabled = false;
    //Button4.Enabled = false;


    }
```

Comment: The error message seems clear to me. Without a good [mcve] it's impossible to know for sure what you're doing, but it appears that the `Connect()` method returns a value of type `long` and you're trying to store it in a variable of type `int`. If you know for sure the value will fit in an `int`, you can just cast. Otherwise, you need to declare the variable as `long`.

Comment: The connect method is probably returning the long value but you are trying to put it in int, converting type from int to long will fix the error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30579114/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-long-to-int

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the error message you get, you have only to change the type of the variable called `MyKADSts`.

```
long MyKADSts = 0;
```

Its type should be a 64-bit integer (`long`) and not a 32-bit integer (`int`). Apparently, you cannot assign a 64-bit integer to a 32-bit integer.

Comment: -> `cannot assign a 64-bit integer value to a 32-bit integer variable`

Comment: @mmcrae do you disaggree with this phrase? Is it something wrong?  Thanks in advance for your response.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `MyKad.Connect()` is defined like the following:

```
public long Connect() 
{
  // ...
}
```

You can't implicitly assign the `long` value returned by that method to an integer local variable `MyKADSts`. This is because `long` (`Int64`) can hold numbers than can't fit inside `int`(`Int32`).

So you need to change your code as follows:

```
long MyKADSts = MyKad.Connect();
```

If you really have a valid reason for `MyKADSts` to be an `int`, you need to explicitly convert the value as the error states:

```
long MyKADSts = (int)MyKad.Connect();
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, when I tried to assign a ContactNo(declared as Bigint in SQL) with the number 9874561230 in C# using LINQ.

I fixed it using the below code:

```
dynamic mobile = 9874561230;
newEmployee.ContactNo = (int)mobile;
```